# Type 'CGColor' has no member 'secondary' - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to setup the background color in a `ZStack` and I need the opposite of the theme so I create a blur effect, when I try:

```
ZStack {
    Color(.secondary).ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all).opacity(0.3)
}
```

It says:

```
Type 'CGColor' has no member 'secondary'
```

[image]

What would be an alternative native solution for this?

I came up with this idea since you are able to apply this color like this:

```
.foregroundColor(.secondary)
```

pd: I'm using SwiftUI 3.0

Comment: What type of thing are you trying to pass? UIColor.secondary? That doesn’t exist. There are system colors that are .secondarySomething . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors

Comment: @WarrenBurton for example on a given text I can do this: `.foregroundColor(.secondary)` I came up with the idea of doing the same for the view but I see it doesn't work. So what would be the approach to get the color inverse to the theme color in a simple color like that?  Since in the above I can also do .green or .white, I thought to do the same with .secondary, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`secondary` is a static property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/secondary).

You use those with a dot on the type name, not as an argument to an initializer.

```swift
 Color.secondary.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all).opacity(0.3)
```

Comment: I'm not following, it's the same I posted above

Comment: I didn't edit. Oops.

Comment: there you go! now it works, I knew there was a way ahaha, just a little hicop in the syntax. Thanks, will accept in 2 min